# PyOWM No attribute

Tags: python, openweathermap

I'm having a bit of a problem using pyowm for the the first time it shows error:

```
'OWM' object has no attribute 'weather_at_place'
```

My code

```
import pyowm

owm = pyowm.OWM('42901314474499fbf7a3f3e5c49b6ad9')
obs = owm.weather_at_place('San Francisco, US')
Print(obs)
```

Comment: Sorry for the way I wrote the code

Comment: owm = pyowm.OWM('4290xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx6ad9')

Comment: In the error message it says OWM, but in your code it says owm

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed the latest version of PyOwm? If yes, uninstall it, and install the previous version using the following command:

- pip install pyowm==2.10.0

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed the latest version of PyOwm? If yes, uninstall it, and install the previous version using the following command:

```
pip install pyowm==2.10.0
```

If you still want to use the latest version of PyOwm then check out the code below:

```
owm = pyowm.OWM('your api key')
city = 'your city'
mgr = owm.weather_manager()
location = mgr.weather_at_place(city)
weather = location.weather
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code snippet.

```
import pyowm

owm = pyowm.OWM('your-api-key')
mng = owm.weather_manager()
obs = mng.weather_at_place(city)
```